# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, sequential

When I am writing the code for the Rainfall prediction using the Australia dataset I am getting the error during the fitting the ann model and running the epoch value for 10 .I am using the libraries such as numpy, pandas , matplotlib , seaborn as importing .For the running of the model I am using the Keras for the dense and sequential search.I am also using the standard scalar for normalizing the value of x.
I am getting the error in this line -
ann.fit(x_train,y_train, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 10, verbose = 1)
Below is my error -
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)
Below is my code-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('weatherAUS.csv')

df.head()

df.columns

plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
df['MaxTemp'].plot()

plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
sns.boxplot(x='RainToday',y='MaxTemp',data = df,palette ='winter')

df['Rainfall'].plot(kind= 'hist', bins=30, color='orange', figsize= (16,7))

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df.info()

df.dropna(inplace= True)

X=df[['Rainfall','MaxTemp','MinTemp']]
y=df[['RainToday','RainTomorrow']]

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state= 41)

#normalization to X values
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
xtrain = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
xtest = scaler.transform(x_test)

import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

ann = Sequential()
ann.add(Dense(units=32, init='uniform', activation='relu', input_dim = 3))
ann.add(Dense(units=16, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
ann.add(Dense(units=1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
ann.compile(optimizer ='adam', loss= 'mean_squared_error', metrics= ['accuracy'])

ann.fit(x_train,y_train, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 10, verbose = 1)

Y_pred = ann.predict(x_test)
Y_pred = [1 if y>=0.5 else 0 for y in  Y_pred]
print(Y_pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the code

```
y=df[['RainToday','RainTomorrow']]
```

y should be a single column. You are trying to predict if it will rain tomorrow. RainToday is a feature that should be in X_train. I suggest you go an excellent tutorial that uses this dataset. It is located [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lm7BmXqmtpg)